# $X_1,X_2$ are independent with a common distribution function $F$. $X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2$ are independent implies that $F$ is normal distribution function

Tags: probability

I meet a problem. Given independent variables $X_1,X_2$ with a common distribution function $F$, I want to show that $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are independent if and only if $F$ is normal distribution function. I have completed the proof of sufficiency, but how can I prove the necessity?

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post with the key steps you used to prove sufficiency. Then everybody could profit from the full proof if your question gets answered.

Comment: This is  a well known characterization of normal distribution. Refer to Lucaks book on chracteristic functions.

Comment: For a much more general result see: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-28/issue-1/On-a-Characterization-of-the-Normal-Distribution-from-Properties-of/10.1214/aoms/1177707041.full

Comment: @Surb The result is available in infinitely many places and the proof is non-trivial. I don't think  a proof should be reproduced here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy "infinitely many places"  :D that is a lot. But I guess you make a fair point (I don't know the proof so could not really judge). Also, the references you pointed to seem to do the job very well.